# Restoring a managed SQL instance in Azure using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to figure out how to restore a database from one managed SQL instance to another. I'm following the tutorials, but I keep running into inscrutable error messages.

Here's my command:

```
Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase `
    -Name "SomeDatabase" `
    -InstanceName "our-oltp-dev" `
    -ResourceGroupName "dev-managedsqlinstances" `
    -PointInTime "4/7/2020 12:00:00" `
    -TargetInstanceDatabaseName "SomeDatabase_FROM_DEV" `
    -TargetInstanceName "our-oltp-sandbox" `
    -TargetResourceGroupName "sandbox-managedsqlinstances"
```

Here's the output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase `
    -Name "SomeDatabase" `
    -InstanceName "our-oltp-dev" `
    -ResourceGroupName "dev-managedsqlinstances" `
    -PointInTime "4/7/2020 12:00:00" `
    -TargetInstanceDatabaseName "SomeDatabase_FROM_DEV" `
    -TargetInstanceName "our-oltp-sandbox" `
    -TargetResourceGroupName "sandbox-managedsqlinstances"
Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ManagedDatabase.Cmdlet.RestoreAzureRmSqlManagedDatabase
```

It's a copy-and-paste from the Azure docs; so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the error,  you do not use the right parameter data type. Please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/restore-azsqlinstancedatabase?view=azps-3.7.0#parameters) to check it.

Comment: @jim-xu I have read the docs. I came up with nothing. Posting on SO is my absolute last resort. Furthermore, I don't see a mention of data type issues anywhere in the error output, so I'm not sure where you're getting that.

Comment: According to the document, the PointInTime should be Datatime type( https://i.stack.imgur.com/01OzV.png), but you use string.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to pass the `PointInTime` as a `DateTime` instead of `String`, you could specify the `4/7/2020 12:00:00` as below.

**Sample:**

```
$PointInTime = Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 4 -Day 7 -Hour 12 -Minute 0 -Second 0
Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase `
    -Name "SomeDatabase" `
    -InstanceName "our-oltp-dev" `
    -ResourceGroupName "dev-managedsqlinstances" `
    -PointInTime $PointInTime `
    -TargetInstanceDatabaseName "SomeDatabase_FROM_DEV" `
    -TargetInstanceName "our-oltp-sandbox" `
    -TargetResourceGroupName "sandbox-managedsqlinstances"
```